# I want to get the windows OS ids from Microsoft Windows Update (WU) offline scan file

Tags: windows

Offline scanning for windows updates requires the download of a signed file, `wsusscn2.cab`, from Windows Update.

The `wsusscn2.cab` contains metadata about security-related updates that are published by Microsoft.

I need to get windows OSes specific identifiers that appear in `wsusscn2.cab` or from another source.

To get this information form `wsusscn2.cab` and extractor of cab is need and a specific xml parser. But because I need only the OS identifiers I hope I can find them also from other sources.

I searched on internet, in Microsoft forums, docs and I didn't found a table or something similar regarding the identifiers. I can find some OS ids on internet but nothing that have all OS ids, or a good parser. Also I searched for a in depth description of the schema used for xmls but I didn't found one.

Example about how I want the information to be extracted:

```
Windows Server 2016: 569e8e8f-c6cd-42c8-92a3-efbb20a0f6f5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find your list in the project
[WSUS Offline Update](https://gitlab.com/wsusoffline/wsusoffline/-/releases).

Download and unpack the Zip file, then have a look the the following two files
that I list below, each with a small excerpt:

**ProductIds-final.txt**

```
558f4bc3-4827-49e1-accf-ea79fd72d4c9=Windows XP
56750722-19b4-4449-a547-5b68f19eee38=Microsoft SQL Server 2012
569e8e8f-c6cd-42c8-92a3-efbb20a0f6f5=Windows Server 2016
575d68e2-7c94-48f9-a04f-4b68555d972d=Windows Small Business Server 2008
589db546-7849-47f5-bbc0-1f66cf12f5c2=Windows 8 Embedded
```

**ProductIds-final-inverted.txt**

This file has the same contents but sorted better for your purpose:

```
Windows 10 GDR-DU=abc45868-0c9c-4bc0-a36d-03d54113baf4
Windows 10 LTSB=d2085b71-5f1f-43a9-880d-ed159016d5c6
Windows 10, version 1903 and later=b3c75dc1-155f-4be4-b015-3f1a91758e52
Windows 10=a3c2375d-0c8a-42f9-bce0-28333e198407
Windows 2000=3b4b8621-726e-43a6-b43b-37d07ec7019f
Windows 7=bfe5b177-a086-47a0-b102-097e4fa1f807
Windows 8 Embedded=589db546-7849-47f5-bbc0-1f66cf12f5c2
Windows 8.1=6407468e-edc7-4ecd-8c32-521f64cee65e
Windows 8=2ee2ad83-828c-4405-9479-544d767993fc
Windows Admin Center=b1b8f641-1ff2-4ae6-b247-4fe7503787be
Windows Embedded Standard 7=f4b9c883-f4db-4fb5-b204-3343c11fa021
Windows Essential Business Server 2008 Setup Updates=6966a762-0c7c-4261-bd07-fb12b4673347
Windows Essential Business Server 2008=e9b56b9a-0ca9-4b3e-91d4-bdcf1ac7d94d
Windows Insider Pre-Release=ca006cfb-49eb-439b-880a-1312e1fc9713
Windows Live=0ea196ba-7a32-4e76-afd8-46bd54ecd3c6
Windows RT 8.1=2c62603e-7a60-4832-9a14-cfdfd2d71b9a
Windows Server 2003, Datacenter Edition=7f44c2a7-bc36-470b-be3b-c01b6dc5dd4e
Windows Server 2003=dbf57a08-0d5a-46ff-b30c-7715eb9498e9
Windows Server 2008 R2=fdfe8200-9d98-44ba-a12a-772282bf60ef
Windows Server 2008=ba0ae9cc-5f01-40b4-ac3f-50192b5d6aaf
Windows Server 2012 R2=d31bd4c3-d872-41c9-a2e7-231f372588cb
Windows Server 2012=a105a108-7c9b-4518-bbbe-73f0fe30012b
Windows Server 2016=569e8e8f-c6cd-42c8-92a3-efbb20a0f6f5
Windows Server 2019=f702a48c-919b-45d6-9aef-ca4248d50397
Windows Server Solutions Best Practices Analyzer 1.0=eef074e9-61d6-4dac-b102-3dbe15fff3ea
Windows Server, version 1903 and later=21210d67-50bc-4254-a695-281765e10665
Windows Small Business Server 2008=575d68e2-7c94-48f9-a04f-4b68555d972d
Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard=1556fc1d-f20e-4790-848e-90b7cdbedfda
Windows Vista=26997d30-08ce-4f25-b2de-699c36a8033a
Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2003=a4bedb1d-a809-4f63-9b49-3fe31967b6d0
Windows XP Embedded=874a7757-3a13-43b2-a7f2-cf2ff43dd6bf
Windows XP x64 Edition=4cb6ebd5-e38a-4826-9f76-1416a6f563b0
Windows XP=558f4bc3-4827-49e1-accf-ea79fd72d4c9
```